# BackGroundWorker Thread when Application is Closed

Tags: c#, mvvm, backgroundworker

Here is my Scenario:-

I have a BackGroundWorker Thread which is subscribed to 2 events DoWork and RunWorkerCompleted .What I am doing is in DoWork event I am doing timetaking task and Updating the UI that is Starting the Loader using MainThread and on RunWorkerComplete I am Updating My UI that is Stopping the Loader.

Now what I want to make sure that when my application gets terminated while the BackgroundWorker is ON that is loader is spinning.I want to make sure that it Kills the BakcgroundWorker Thread or at least the termination of the Application results in thread SAFE when the LOADER is ON.

Does Dispose will give any HElp..? or DynamicGarbageCollection will handle the unusedObjects when application termination occurs will do the same thing which Dispose does.??

Hope I am Clear..How can I achieve that.??

Comment: Your background worker can't survive when your `App Terminates`. what do you mean by App termination?

Comment: Are you looking for [`CancelAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.cancelasync.aspx)? All background threads are disposed when the application closes

Comment: No I am not looking for cancelAsync

Comment: Yes, you are looking for CancelAsync. At the very least implementing it is a good precaution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bgw thread itself will be stopped when your App terminates but you have to take care not to update controls on a Closed/Closing Form.

Do not call Dispose() here. You can Cancel the backgroundworker but the code in DoWork() must comply.

Comment: On closing  my Application I am just updating my Log file.But the point is while the spinner is still  ON and I terminate my Application.Will that result in a Thread Safe State or I need to take care of something at that point of time.

Comment: Depends on a lot of thing. Your DoWork code should be defensive and preferably stoppable.

Comment: on Using Cancelasync-I am Getting this exception--This BackgroundWorker states that it doesn't support cancellation. Modify WorkerSupportsCancellation to state that it does support cancellation.

Comment: Yes, set the boolean poperty `WorkerSupportsCancellation ` to `true` first. And modify the DoWork code to look at CancelationPending.

Comment: How does cancellationpending will help..?

Answer (score 0):

By definition, a background thread will not be able to keep the host process running (as opposed to a foreground thread - such as the thread that renders the UI components).

See the MSDN documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h339syd0.aspx